# JavaScript very simple form validation for 2 different input

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

l am trying to teach myself simple but not very boring (avoiding usage of alert) way of form validations and now I just made up one very plain form and wanted to validate it using 1 function. But for some reason the form is not validating, any suggestions maybe?

My code:

```
<form id='test' onSubmit="return ValidateForm()">
Name * <input id="name" type="text"><span id="wrongname" class="error">This is a    required field</span>
Email* <input id="email" type="text"><span id="wrongemail" class="error">This is a required field</span>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</div>
</form>

function ValidateForm() {
document.getElementById('test').onsubmit=function(){
  if(document.getElementById('name').value=""){
    document.getElementById('wrongname').style.display="block";
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
    if (email.value.search( /^[a-zA-Z]+([_\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/ ) == -1){
alert(“Wrong email”);
return false;
}
  }
}

.error{
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
```

in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QvNFf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykuY4/)

Changes:

- Removed the inline `onsubmit` handler because you assign it in the JavaScript
- Moved the `onsubmit` out of the ValidateForm function and assigned this function as the submit handler
- Fixed bad quotes in your `alert()`
- Changed `=` comparison operator to `==`. Only use a single `=` for assignments
- Removed `return true` because this stops the email validation from being executed
- Changed `email` to `document.getElementById('email')`

Updated code:

```
function ValidateForm() {

    if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('wrongname').style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById('email').value.search(/^[a-zA-Z]+([_\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/) == -1) {
        alert("Wrong email");
        return false;
    }
}

document.getElementById('test').onsubmit = ValidateForm;
```

Comment: I have played around with the code and decided to change the second part for email and did this ==> http://jsfiddle.net/UCqrV/

Comment: @But the thing is, I want to get both error message in the same time if both fields are empty.

Comment: But it gives the error message step by step, not both in the same time, I don't know what I am doing wrong, can you check the code please?

Comment: To do that you need to use a variable instead of returning false immediately. Also hide the error if the user corrects the field. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UCqrV/1/

Answer (score 2):

A couple things go wrong here:

- `document.getElementById('test').onsubmit = function () {}` duplicates the `onsubmit` attribute
- jsfiddle setup needs to be tweaked in order to make it work
- choose framework and extensions `no wrap - in body`
- html: use the label tags in forms to enhance usability
- js: make sure you use valid quotes => `alert(“Wrong email”);` is not the same as `alert("Wrong email");` and will result in parsing errors.
- js: if you need to check a value, make sure to use it's proper operator `==` or even better `===` which will check against it's type as well.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/YXadB/)

**[update]**

and remove the return true for email ^^

Comment: This only corrects the name validation, the email validation still doesn't work (need to remove the `return true`).

Comment: Yeah, was going to check that afterwards but you beat me to it, hence the +1. cheers